# How to open up a port firewall on Ubunto internally and how to verify it

Tags: nginx, amazon-web-services, http, port, queue

## Background

I got an aws machine that's running both a laravel app, and now I've tried to install [beanstalk console](https://github.com/ptrofimov/beanstalk_console). This is what the nginx config file of the laravel app look like:

```
include forge-conf/default/before/*;

server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name default;
    root /home/forge/default/public;

    # FORGE SSL (DO NOT REMOVE!)
    # ssl_certificate;
    # ssl_certificate_key;

    ssl_protocols ..
    ssl_ciphers ..
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_dhparam ..

    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";

    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    charset utf-8;

    # FORGE CONFIG (DOT NOT REMOVE!)
    include forge-conf/default/server/*;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    access_log off;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/default-error.log error;

    error_page 404 /index.php;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

this is what the nginx config file of the beanstalk app looks like:

```
server {
    listen 8080;
    listen [::]:8080;
    server_name beanstalk_server;
    root /home/forge/beanstalk-console/public;

    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    error_log  /var/log/nginx/default-error.log error;

    error_page 404 /index.php;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

## Question

when I try to hit `server-ip:8080`, I get the error:

```
server-ip took too long to respond.
```

I've made sure this isn't a permissions thing, as I updated the inbound rules for the aws instance like so:

[image]

but still no luck, I know this isn't a problem with the beanstalk console itself, b/c if i simply switch ports (ie if make the beanstalk console listen to port 80 instead of 8080, it works just fine.. I also tried a different port like 1515 and it still didn't work)..

also i know that localhost:8080 works just fine, b/c running

```
wget localhost:8080
```

does return the html site for beanstalk.

one thing to keep in mind is that my aws machine is also sitting behind a load balancer.. which forwards http requests at the load balancer at port 80 to port 80 of the machine.. but i don't think that would make any difference

[image]

what do i do?

## update

i checked my access log (`tail -f /var/log/nginx/access.logtail -f /var/log/nginx/access.log`) and error logs (`$ tail -f /var/log/nginx/error.log`) and found nothing there when i tried to access beanstalk

this is the output of my netstat command

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      11997/nginx -g daem
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8080            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      11997/nginx -g daem
tcp        0      0 10.0.17.158:80          10.0.1.251:19336        ESTABLISHED 11998/nginx: worker
tcp        0      0 10.0.17.158:80          10.0.17.87:62074        ESTABLISHED 11998/nginx: worker
tcp        0      0 10.0.17.158:80          10.0.17.101:59938       ESTABLISHED 11998/nginx: worker
tcp        0      0 10.0.17.158:80          10.0.17.101:60988       ESTABLISHED 11998/nginx: worker
tcp        0      0 10.0.17.158:80          10.0.1.21:63633         ESTABLISHED 11998/nginx: worker
tcp        0      0 10.0.17.158:80          10.0.1.21:62603         ESTABLISHED 11998/nginx: worker
tcp        0      0 10.0.17.158:80          10.0.17.87:63110        ESTABLISHED 11998/nginx: worker
tcp        0      0 10.0.17.158:80          10.0.1.251:20344        ESTABLISHED 11998/nginx: worker
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      11997/nginx -g daem
tcp6       0      0 :::8080                 :::*                    LISTEN      11997/nginx -g daem
```

## update 2: firewall settings

It seems port 8080 is not firewalled.. see this [command](https://askubuntu.com/a/328293/131945):

```
netstat -ntlp | grep LISTEN
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:11300           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:587           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:6379            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:11211           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      11998/nginx: worker
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8080            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      11998/nginx: worker
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5432            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
tcp6       0      0 :::3306                 :::*                    LISTEN      -
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      11998/nginx: worker
tcp6       0      0 :::8080                 :::*                    LISTEN      11998/nginx: worker
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      -
tcp6       0      0 :::5432                 :::*                    LISTEN      -
```

I also ran nmap:

```
nmap 10.0.17.158

Starting Nmap 7.01 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2017-10-11 10:38 EEST
Nmap scan report for 10.0.17.158
Host is up (0.000068s latency).
Not shown: 995 closed ports
PORT     STATE SERVICE
22/tcp   open  ssh
80/tcp   open  http
3306/tcp open  mysql
5432/tcp open  postgresql
8080/tcp open  http-proxy
```

Comment: Does the request show in the Nginx logs? If so please edit your question to add the log line, particularly the response code. Also check your application logs that Nginx is sitting in front of, I suspect a timeout there. "Too long to respond" suggests the server is listening on 8080 and is sending the request off to the fast_cgi but it's not getting a response.

Comment: @Tim updated the question.. nothing shows up on nginx error or access logs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building on up Shadi's answer, and after checking that AWS was indeed routing the 8080 port to the machine, the issue turned out from the `iptables`.

I'm not sure how to check if a port is blocked or not using iptables, but here's a command that will allow port 8080:

This is the iptables command that allows access to port 8080 from an OS level:

```
sudo iptables -I INPUT 1 -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 8080 -j ACCEPT
```

(for reference on the iptables command, see this [excellent post](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-firewall-using-iptables-on-ubuntu-14-04), direct quotes are formatted as such, and I also added my own explanations to the rest):

> -I INPUT 1: The -I flag tells iptables to insert a rule. This is
>   different than the -A flag which appends a rule to the end. The -I
>   flag takes a chain and the rule position where you want to insert the
>   new rule.
>
> in this case, we're adding this rule as the very first rule of the
>   INPUT chain. This will bump the rest of the rules down. We want this
>   at the top because it is fundamental and should not be affected by
>   subsequent rules.

-i eth0: This component of the rule matches if the interface that the packet is using is the "eth0" interface (ethernet).

-p tcp: this is simply specifying the tcp protocol

-- dport 8080: the port we're talking about

> -j ACCEPT: This specifies the target of matching packets. Here, we tell iptables that packets that match the preceding criteria should be
>   accepted and allowed through.

### How to check if the port is opened or not?

As mentioned in the above link as well, you can simply run the following:

```
sudo iptables -S
```

this will output a *lot* of rules, depending on your setup. To cut through the chase, just run this command

```
$ sudo iptables -S | grep "dport 8080"
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8080 -j ACCEPT
```

so from there you can immediately know what's going on with port 8080

### How to persist the iptables command?

Just use the `iptables-persistent` package:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install iptables-persistent
```

It will persist the iptables rules on fresh install, refer to the above link for more details

Comment: This actually fixed my problem.. however I can't award the correct answer unless I know how to find out that a port is firewalled or not.. otherwise this command will look like a shot in the dark

Answer (score 2):

Since localhost:8080 works thus the request from outside is not reaching your server that is listening on that port 8080. Check the below

1. The AWS is routing requests to your server (which should be the case based on your config)
2. Check the firewall configuration for the instance you have. What OS you are using? probably the config deny access to that port

Comment: this is an ubuntu OS.. i'll check the OS firewalls

Comment: updated the question.. not sure if i'm doing it right